# Issue with installing the SFDX CLI in Linux

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, cli, install, sfdx-error

I had some issues with my SFDX CLI as I was not able to use SFDX commands from the terminal of my VS Code in Linux. So I looked up on the web and as part of one solution that I found on web, I was advised to uninstall it and install it back. Thus I un-installed it.

Now when I try to install it back with npm i.e. by running this command

> sudo npm install sfdx-cli --global

my installation is getting completed at the middle and it is showing complete. Also when I verify my installation, I can see that it is not installed. I tried uninstalling and installing back many times, but every time the same thing is happening. I have attached the screenshots for the reference. Please help me on this!!!

Thanks in advance !!! [image: Uninstalled and tried to install it back.]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved. It just took a long time to install from the point of which I have put up the screenshot. Initially I thought it got stuck in the middle but it was processing at that time and you got to wait some more time before the installation picks up.